# How to count the number of button presses then play a sequence?

Tags: led, button

1. When I press the button once, sequence s1() plays.
2. When I press the button twice, sequence s2() plays.
3. When I press the button thrice, sequence s3() plays.
4. When I press the button 4 times, sequence s4() plays.

---

```
const int buttonPin = 10;  
int buttonState = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //initialize pin 2 - 9 as output
  for(int i=2;i<=9;i++){ 
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    s1();
    s2();
    s3();
    s4();
  }
}

void s1() {
  int i = 2 ;
  for(int z=0;z<=1;z++) {
    for(int x=i;x<=9;x++) {
      digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(x-1,LOW);
      delay(500);
      i = i + 1;
    }
    i = 2;
    if(i = 2) {
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    }
  }
}

void s2(){
  int y = 9;
  for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
    for(int x=2;x<=5;x++) {
      if(y>=1) {
        digitalWrite(x,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(y,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        y = y - 1;
      }
    }
    off();
    y = 9;
    delay(500);
  }
}

void s3() {
  for(int i=0;i<=2;i++) {
    for(int z=2; z<=9;z++) {
      if(z % 2 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(z,HIGH);
      }
    }
    delay(500);
    for(int z=2; z<=9;z++) {
      if(z % 2 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(z,LOW);
      }
    }
    delay(500);
    for(int z=2; z<=9;z++) {
      if(z % 2 != 0) {
        digitalWrite(z,HIGH);
      }
    }
    delay(500);
    for(int z=2; z<=9;z++) {
      if(z % 2 != 0) {
        digitalWrite(z,LOW);
      }
    }
    delay(500);
  }
}

void s4() {
  for(int i=0;i<=2;i++) {
    for(int x=2;x<=9;x++) {
      digitalWrite(x,HIGH);
      delay(500);
    }
    off();
    delay(500);
  }
}

void off() {
  for(int i=2;i<=9;i++) {
    digitalWrite(i,LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should tell us the preblem you are having.

Comment: You didn't like my solution on [so] so you have to crosspost this question here?

Comment: Someone suggested on his question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388020/arduino-count-the-number-of-button-press-then-play-sequence/ that he take it here. However cross-posting is normally discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

That's not that complex, please have a look at the following code: not the most elegant solution ever, but should be working (I didn't compile it as I'm currently on launch break in the office)

```
#define LONGEST_PAUSE 1000
unsigned long lastClick;
unsigned int counter;

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
    // button is pressed
    while(digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)) {
      delay(1); // wait until button released
    }
    lastClick = millis();
    counter++;
  }
  if (counter > 0 && (millis() - lastClick) >= LONGEST_PAUSE) { // 1s passed since last click: let's play!
    switch(counter) {
      case 1:
        s1(); break;
      case 2:
        s2(); break;
      case 3:
        s3(); break;
      case 4:
        s4(); break;
      default:
        // what if I keep clicking?!?
    }
    counter = 0; // reset the counter
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to break the loop when i press the button when the loop is running?

Comment: The OP apparently wishes to (and I'm quoting him) _"break the loop when I press the button the the loop is running"_

While this might be a question on it's own... 
**NO**, if you exit the `loop()` function then (by default) your Arduino stops doing **anything** and just sits there dissipating energy into heat, not much though. With some little effort you can instruct it to **reboot**.

Comment: If my answer solved the problem stated into your question you should accept it and create a new question accordingly to your updated needs.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use pinchange interrupt or simple INT0 interrupt for the buttons to count the press.
Check [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt).

on ISR, you can count the press.

```
int count=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), countFn, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  switch(count){
      // all cases here
  }
  count=0;
  delay(2000); // this delay is important to give enough time for a number of presses for the user
}

void countFn() {
  count++;
}
```